# Calling a MVC Controller Method when I select an option on a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a select tag with two options. I would like to call a method on my controller when a option is selected.

The method in the controller, contains a Switch that will set 3 Uints based on the selected option. I then want to return back to the original view that called the Action.

I am a little stumped on one, how to trigger the action in the view and on two how to redirect to the calling view.

My View is below

```
@using <The controller name goes here>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Stuff";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Stuff</h2>
<p>More Stuff</p>
<label>Select a Room: </label>
<!-- I need to add Code that will loop through the database and provide rooms. 
        I will need to provide a query that will be called on page load.-->

<select id="roomList">
    <option value="1B^1001^01">1B^1001^01</option>
    <option value="1B^1002^01">1B^1002^01</option>
</select><br /><br />
```

The Controller action is below.

```
public Action getRoomNumber(string roomNumber, ref uint BVInstance, ref uint AVInstance, ref uint MVInstance)
        {

            switch(roomNumber)
            {
                case ("1B^1001^01"):
                    BVInstance = 3000018;
                    AVInstance = 3000022;
                    MvInstance = 3000040;
                    break;

                case("1B^1002^01"):
                    BVInstance = 3000020;
                    AVInstance = 3000023;
                    MvInstance = 3000042;
                    break;

                default:

                    break;
            }

            return Redirect()
        }
```

Comment: are you trying to return the `ref` values back to the view?  you might want to watch the video pluralsight made for mvc4 http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building

Comment: I am actually passing them back to the controller to use with another method. They will never reach the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple way if you use Jquery :

```
$("#roomList").change(function() {
    $(this).parents("form").submit();
});
```

But you also need to update your html (add a form around your select) :

```
<form action="controller/action">
  <select id="roomList">
    <option value="1B^1001^01">1B^1001^01</option>
    <option value="1B^1002^01">1B^1002^01</option>
  </select><br /><br />
</form>
```

In your cs code, for the redirection, actions can return 2 objects that can handle your redirection :

```
return RedirectToAction("action");
```

or

```
return View("viewName"); //Not quite sure about the parameters here, but you can read the doc ;-)
```

Comment: I assume that controller/action and action are placeholders for the values?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up an event handler in JavaScript for the change event of the  `<select>`.  In that handler you will have an AJAX call to your controller.

```
$("#roomList").on("change", function() {
        $.ajax({               {
              url: @Url.Action("getRoomNumber", "SomeController", new {roomNumber = $("#roomList :selected").text()}),
              context: document.body
        }).done(function() {
               // do whatever you need to do in your view here
               alert("Done!");
           });
});
```

I didn't pass in those reference variables to the controller, so you will need to do that in order for your controller action to change them.

Answer (score 0):

A `SELECT` element won't be able to submit a form by itself. You would need to use some form of JavaScript to submit the form when the `SELECT` changes.

using jQuery:

```
$("#roomList").on("change", function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

then the Controller Action can either return the name of the View or redirect to the Action that displays the View.

Comment: Ok, so I have to use a form submission. I know I've used the on change to trigger JQuery on the client side. But what I'm reading is that since this is calling a controller method it has to use the form. Let me see if I can get this to work. Thanks.

Comment: yes, there needs to be a form wrapped around all form elements. in MVC Razor views, you can use `@using(Html.BeginForm()) { ... code ... }`